# Terminal as transparent wallpaper in xmonad

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I recently switched to xmonad and I'm trying to pimp it up a bit. I'd like to set up a terminal as a transparent background (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Terminal_as_a_transparent_wallpaper).
Basically, I'd need a window that sits on the bottom of each workspace, that cannot be moved, tiled or closed and gets focus only when it's the only window open in that workspace. So far, I've managed to make the window boring to get the focus behavior I want, but I cannot make it float and stay below everything else. Is there any way to accomplish it? Or maybe a way to doIgnore the window but allow focus on it to type commands?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can let `xmonad` ignore it, like what you did to `conky` or `plank`.

my example (https://github.com/suzumiyasmith/MyXmonad/blob/d71796f9a72f98d4b97dcaebe9d4905841431b8b/src/xmonad.hs#L145)

1. set a specific class name for that window.
2. get the window via name or class query.
3. ignore it.

Comment: After tried several times to solve the stupid indent error(yeah, I am using 2 spaces) in code formatting.

Comment: I already tried that, but if xmonad completely ingores that window, that terminal never gets focus so I cannot input text on it... Ideally I'd like it to get focus when there's no other open window in that given workspace.

Comment: It might use some kinds of `hook`(not sure). I thought you serve the terminal as dynamic wallpaper